# IP адрес устройств, подключённых к одной сети

Tags: c#, сеть, ip

Не могу разобраться в теме IP. Создадим ситуацию: у нас существуют 4 устройства одной организации N и все они подключены к одной Wifi сети этой организации N. Итак, вопросы, которые меня интересуют:

1. Какие части ip у них будут одинаковыми, чтобы можно было понять, что они подключены к данной сети организации N? Или как вообще понять, что они подключены к этой сети?
2. Допустим, что это всё происходит в случае, когда у нас ip адрес роутера статический. А что будет, если данный адрес будет динамическим, и будет постоянно изменяться при перезапуске? Это как-то повлияет на устройства, которые подключены к данному WIfi? Может у них изменится какая-то часть адреса?

Сама проблема, которую я пытаюсь решить:

Нужно получить IP адрес устройств, с которого была запущена программа и сравнить его образцом. Если они похожи, то вывести сообщение об этом. Тоже самое сделать для другого устройства, подключенного к данной сети. И, например, сделать это для устройства, которое не подключено к данной сети и вывести для него соответствующее сообщение

P. S. Пишу код на C#, поэтому будет очень круто, если подскажите библиотеку, через которую можно реализовать это

Comment: Это всё целиком и полностью зависит от конкретных настроек роутера и конкретных настроек подключающихся устройств. При желании можно сделать так, чтобы общих частей ip вообще не было. Кроме того, в разных сетях могут быть одинаковые ip, так что похожесть ничего не скажет о том, подключено ли устройство к данной сети на самом деле

Comment: Другими словами, невозможно без дополнительных манипуляций с конкретным роутером сделать это? Тогда немного другой вопрос: можно ли получить статический ip и тем самым аутентифицировать пользователя? Например, по мак-адресу. Или это тоже никак не реализовать?

Comment: 1. для этого существует маска подсети, с помощью которой можно определить принадлежит ли адрес сети или нет. 2. никак не повлияют, т.к. у устройств будет адрес выданный роутером. 3. А последний абзац про проверку я не совсем понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Какие части ip у них будут одинаковыми,

есть такое понятие, как маска подсети. она для домашних сетей часто выглядит как /24 (очень типовое значение). Это значит, что первые 24 бита ipv4 адреса будет совпадать. В коде это можно проверить с помощью битовых операций - маска /24 это 255.255.255.0 == 0xFFFFFF00. Скорее всего это значение Вы видели в настройках сети рядом возле айпи.

> чтобы можно было понять, что они подключены к данной сети организации N?

а вот тут нужно знать характеристики сети организации N. В общем случае никак.

> Или как вообще понять, что они подключены к этой сети?

Если айпи белый или серый, то тут все просто - проверили по базам (например, ipinfo.io) и сравнили. Если же это адрес внуренний, то тут просто знание айпи никак не поможет. у тысяч организаций внутренние айпи в диапазоне 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255. Но если при этом знать ещё и внешний айпи, то тут все стает немного проще - если внешний айпи одинаковый, то, возможно, они действительно в одной подсети. Хотя и обратное тоже не всегда возможно - у организации может быть несколько внешних айпи.

> Допустим, что это всё происходит в случае, когда у нас ip адрес роутера статический. А что будет, если данный адрес будет динамическим, и будет постоянно изменяться при перезапуске? Это как-то повлияет на устройства, которые подключены к данному WIfi? Может у них изменится какая-то часть адреса?

ага, значит сеть локальная все таки. Обычно, устройство, которое подключается, не знает адреса роутера. Оно ему и не нужно. Но оно обычно вначале запрашивает по dhcp настройки. Но так как не знает кто и что, то делает широковещательный запрос и в пришедшем сообщении есть обычно все что нужно, включая айпи, dns и так далее.

> Нужно получить IP адрес устройств, с которого была запущена программа и сравнить его образцом. Если они похожи, то вывести сообщение об этом. Тоже самое сделать для другого устройства, подключенного к данной сети. И, например, сделать это для устройства, которое не подключено к данной сети и вывести для него соответствующее сообщение

скорее всего Ваша задача имеет два способа решения.

Первый. Возьмите любой сервис, который показывает внешний айпи. тот же https://ipinfo.io/ (он хорош тем, что возвращает json) или что то такое https://www.myexternalip.com/raw (тут вообще текст). И вот этот айпи и сравнивайте с образцом. Скорее всего это то, что Вам нужно. Если У Вас есть свой сервер для этого дела - тогда можете использовать его.

Второй способ. Можно сделать широковещательный запрос в сети. другие устройства будут слушать и отвечать по надобности. Таким образом работает, к примеру, обычная локальная сеть в винде или локальные чаты. И теперь, как минимум, программы внутри одной сети будут знать друг о дружке и смогут обменятся признаками "мы в одной сети".

Посмотрите на такое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616911/c-sharp-udp-broadcast-and-receive-example

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Вы очень помогли мне прояснить непонятные моменты. А будет ли меняться внешний ip-адрес при перезагрузке роутера? Я читал, что при динамическом ip он меняется

Comment: это зависит от провайдера интернета и его настроек (ну или того, к кому подключен роутер). Обычное дело, когда апйи меняется просто в процессе работы и никакой перегрузки.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие части ip у них будут одинаковыми, чтобы можно было понять, что
> они подключены к данной сети организации N? Или как вообще понять, что
> они подключены к этой сети?

Одинаковыми будут части в зависимости от маски подсети, но и в кофейне напротив этой организации могут быть такие же IP. Если вы можете посмотреть их IP, то вероятно вы сами подключены к этой сети и тогда точно можете определить кто в ней есть, необходимо всего лишь просканить ARP через консоль
на linux

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet
```

> Допустим, что это всё происходит в случае, когда у нас ip адрес
> роутера статический. А что будет, если данный адрес будет
> динамическим, и будет постоянно изменяться при перезапуске? Это как-то
> повлияет на устройства, которые подключены к данному WIfi? Может у них
> изменится какая-то часть адреса?

Вам надо понимать, что у роутера есть внешний и внутренний IP, в локальной сети(внутренний) он будет постоянный к нему и будут подключаться внутри сети, а внешний вовсе не волнует локальных пользователей

> Нужно получить IP адрес устройств, с которого была запущена программа
> и сравнить его образцом. Если они похожи, то вывести сообщение об
> этом. Тоже самое сделать для другого устройства, подключенного к
> данной сети. И, например, сделать это для устройства, которое не
> подключено к данной сети и вывести для него соответствующее сообщение

Надо больше информации какого рода программа, работает она локально только или нет. Если вы будете не в локальной сети, то все 4 человека из организации N зайдут в программу, а вы получите 4 раза один и тот же внешний IP